# focus shift in gsp pages

Tags: grails

In a gsp page, the default way of shifting focus in fields is vertical. like i have 10 textboxes, 5 in a column, in my create.gsp page and my focus is on first textbox, then by pressing tab, focus shifts vertically down to the next textbox. My requirement is to shift focus horizontally from left to right, row by row. can anyone help me how to do this. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this with the [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) attribute. In the example below the focus moves from f1 to f3 to f2 according to the ascending order of the tabindex.

```
<input type="text" name="f1" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" name="f2" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" name="f3" tabindex="2" />
```